# Actionscript 3 objects not turning

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, trigonometry

So I'm working on a game and attempting to create a movieclip that turns to point at the mouse, is there anything wrong with this code?

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class Shark extends Sprite
    {
        public function Shark()
        {

            this.x = 300;
            this.y = 200;
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, playGame);
        }

        function playGame(event:Event):void
        {
            var targetX:int = mouseX - this.x;
            var targetY:int = mouseY - this.y;
            this.rotation = Math.atan2(targetY,targetX) * 180 / Math.PI;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Consider expanding on your question to better clarify your problem and desired outcome.  I don't see anything that would produce an error, but I imagine that's not what you're asking for?  Is something not working properly?  Are you just wondering about efficiency?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `mouseX` and `mouseY` are now relative to the object itself. Use `root`'s `mouseX` and `mouseY` properties instead , like:

```
var targetX:int = root.mouseX - this.x;
var targetY:int = root.mouseY - this.y;
```

Comment: @Altrows it is happens to everyone! glad if it helps you!